# SSL Certification for Forms

Tags: ssl

On my home page there are four links: Home, Contact Us, Company News, and Login.

I want Login and Company News to use SSL Certification.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Secure Pages](http://drupal.org/project/securepages) Module to configure https pages, but before that you need to get a valid SSL Certificate and get it installed in your server.